# HDMI audio out of phase

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I have an old PC where I installed a Nvidia GeForce 710 and set it up like a mediacenter linked up via hdmi to my samsung TV.
I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and some times th audio get out of phase and the only way to fix it is tu run

*killall pulseaudio && alsa force-reload*

(or,of course, reboot the system).
Can someone help me to fix this or is it just a problem of my out dated hardware?

Comment: Not just you. I had to adjust it myself an hour ago using: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/537261/chrome-html5-video-out-of-sync-with-audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537261/chrome-html5-video-out-of-sync-with-audio)

Comment: I've installed pavucontrol but the advanced option show in that post is greyed out for my nvidia card. (I'm running ubuntu 16.04 with lxde graphic enviroment).

Comment: Anyway when i rertart pulseaudio and alsa the audio is perfectly synchronized, and later, for unknown reasons messes up. So I'm not shure it is the same problem